# Word to HTML Conversion- Loss of image quality

Tags: microsoft-word, images, conversion, html

I have a word document which has formulas and other things as images.Now when I convert this document to a HTML file (Save as Webpage) the images experience a loss in quality.

This is negligible in small images where original is 55x25 and converted is 53x22 or something similar,but the problem comes in big images where I get loss of around 15 pixels which is very much visible and looks ugly with the size messed up.

The image in word is of .emz type and the exported file is .png.So since PNG is lossless I have no idea why is this occurring and also the 'do not compress images option' is also checked so that images do not experience quality loss.Note that when I try to export each image individually then it gets saved in its original quality.

What is wrong here? Why does word produce images of lesser quality when conversion.Is there any other tool I can use besides the built in word conversion utility that produces better results.

Comment: What Word version do you use?

Comment: It is docx format and I use office 2010

Comment: Is your problem a *loss in quality* (like when you convert .bmp to .jpg; compression) or the automatic reduction of *picture dimensions*?

Comment: I would say both,because when I manually scale in HTML to the required size,it does not look nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the compression setting

```
Click the Office Button, and then click Save As. 
Click Tools, and then click Compress Pictures. 
Click Options. 
Click to clear the Automatically perform basic compression on save check box. 
Click OK. 
In the Compress Pictures dialog box, click Cancel.
Note:  Clicking OK on this dialog will not prevent the issue from occurring.
```

you can also do the same in word 2010 as shown in this picture by going to file > options then follow this window

[image]

Check this setting as well

[image]

for more infomation just follow this link

```
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2002066
```

If all else fails you could simply add the html code yourself to link the image from the source file so you dont need to convert it

```
 <img src="name of image" alt="image description here" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: I am not able to find this menu navigation in word 2010

Comment: I changed the answer to show how you can do it in word 2010

Comment: Yep.I did this already,maybe I didnt explain it my question in a clear manner.But this didnt help either.

Comment: could you show a screenshot of the image before and after the conversion?

Comment: I am sorry but due to copyright,ill not be able to show that.But thanks for your help,ill try out and get back

Comment: ok, well i added more screenshots showing what else you can try, I mean couldnt you simply just add some html code yourself to add the image straight from the source instead of converting it from word?

Comment: The images are actually formulas in word,they do not have a source unless they are created in word.So conversion would be the best option.However if all else fails I think I would have to resort to export pics first then linking my HTML to that.

Comment: ok, well im glad I could somehow help

Comment: >> The images are actually formulas in word ..." In that case you could probably select them, then paste special, as PNG.